# How to have .html files pass through the PHP preprocessor?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php, html, php7

I would like to configure an Apache webserver 2.4.37 to hide the fact that it is serving PHP files.

For this, I renamed all `.php` files to `.html` and inserted the following directive:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

[as suggested here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php).

However, this does not work; all `.html` files are not passed through PHP.  Any ideas?

The version of PHP installed is 7.2.24.

Comment: Stupid question... did you restart apache? I've just tried with apache 2.4.41 and it works.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Yes, I did.

Comment: I've just tried with `Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)` changing the extension to `.py` and worked. Do you want I share the `phpinfo`? I don't know if it could be useful. PHP 7.3.14.

Comment: [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XcFpsNs6mn/](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XcFpsNs6mn/)

Comment: Can you please share the content of your Apache config file? I have a Let'sEncrypt SSL cert with a RewriteRule from HTTP to HTTPS on my config, and this perhaps interferes somehow.

Comment: [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/qKYBzWWqk2/](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/qKYBzWWqk2/)